# Where does opencv come from in spyder

Tags: python, opencv, pip, anaconda, spyder

I'm working on a project where i use Spyder-IDE from anaconda. I just need to download certain opencv version. Therefore i uninstalled my current openCV version from anaconda environment (see image below):

[image: ana]

However, the opencv which i assumingly uninstalled Bibliothek is still being imported in spyder (see image)

[image]

As you see above the library still being imported

I also checked if its installed using pip but didn't find anything

**So where does it come from and how to emove it?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So where does it come from

To find that out, you need to write

```
cv2.__file__
```

> how to remove it?

It depends. If that file name contains directory names related to Anaconda on it, you should use `conda` to do that. If it contains `AppData` and `Python37` or `Python38`, you need to go to that location and remove that directory by hand.

Comment: @k.jbaili, I'm really glad!